# get unselected option from multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple select list. When user unselects the selected option,  I want to know the value of the unselected option made by user. How do I capture it?

My sample code is as below.

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I have following jquery code to allow user to select multiple options

```
$('option').mousedown(function(){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false :true);
});
```

Comment: You want to get the click event, and check if the value of the target is unselected. If so, you just got the unchecked value. I will  make a fiddle right now for you.

Comment: mouse events not supported cross browser. what specifically do you need to do with the value?

Comment: @Casey that simply won't work cross browser

Answer (score 3):

Mouse events aren't available cross browser

My suggestion would be always store array of previous values on the select.

On every change you can then compare to prior value array and once found update the stored array

```
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  var $sel = $(this),
    val = $(this).val(),
    $opts = $sel.children(),
    prevUnselected = $sel.data('unselected');
  // create array of currently unselected 
  var currUnselected = $opts.not(':selected').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
  // see if previous data stored
  if (prevUnselected) {
      // create array of removed values        
      var unselected = currUnselected.reduce(function(a, curr) {
        if ($.inArray(curr, prevUnselected) == -1) {
          a.push(curr)
        }
        return a
      }, []);
      // "unselected" is an array
      if(unselected.length){
        alert('Unselected is ' + unselected.join(', '));  
      }

  }
  $sel.data('unselected', currUnselected)
}).change();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qtkrqeqf/3)**</kbd>

Comment: it works if you uncheck a single item but for multiples, it only gives the last selected value.

Comment: @DinoMyte not sure what you mean. My interpretation is that OP would so something with each value unselected as it is unselected

Comment: @DinoMyte ok...I was only using `Ctrl +click` I see what you mean if use SHift

Comment: it only fails , if you have more than 2 items selected and then you click an item from the selected items, it gives you the removed value from the last selected, not the other 2 ..

Comment: @DinoMyte fixed it to return an array ..thx for heads up. Old story of testing one way manually vs someone else using UI differently. Was working good using Ctrl + click would catch individuals

Comment: Believe in the same theory :)

Answer (score 3):

Great question, i wrote some codes for detecting unselected options using data attributes.

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {  
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var unselected = $(this).find('option:not(:selected)');
    selected.attr('data-selected', '1');
    $.each(unselected, function(index, value){
     if($(this).attr('data-selected') == '1'){
           //this option was selected before
            alert("I was selected before " + $(this).val());
            $(this).attr('data-selected', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="select">
 <option data-selected=0 value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option data-selected=0 value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option data-selected=0 value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option data-selected=0 value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the option that just got unselected, right?

if so, try this:

create a variable "lastSelectedValue" (or whatever you want to call it). When you select an option, assign to it, when you change the selected option, you can get the value and use it, and assign to it again

```
var lastSelectedOption = '';
$('select').on('change', function(){ 
   //do what you need to do
   lastSelectedOption = this.val();
});
```

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/xja61kyx/

updated with multiple: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/xja61kyx/

not sure if this is exactly what you need. please provide feedback

Comment: but OP is dealing with multiple which returns an array. Also `this.val()` is invalid

Comment: @Parag He wanted it with multiple option but you still provided single option.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others, the key would be to compare the previous selected values with current value. Since you need to figure out the removed value, you can check if the `lastSelected.length > currentSelected.length` and then simply replace the currentSelected from the lastSelected to get the results.

```
var lastSelected = "";
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var currentSelected = $(this).val();  
    if (lastSelected.length > currentSelected.length) {
       var a = lastSelected.toString().replace(currentSelected.toString(),"");
        alert("Removed value : " + a.replace(",",""));
     }     
      lastSelected = currentSelected;
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/cw96h622/3/

Comment: Select all option using ```ctrl``` or ```cmd``` then unselect ```Saab``` option while you're holding ```ctrl``` or ```cmd```, you'll see result is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can try make it

```
$('#link_to_id').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
    console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
});
```

With v.text get the Text

With v.value get the Value